# get tree Like Class children using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I built a class Cluster as follow:

```
public  class Cluster
{
    List<Cluster> lstChildClusters=new List<Cluster>();

     public List<Cluster> LstChildClusters
     {    
        get { return lstChildClusters; }
        set { lstChildClusters = value; }
     }

     public    classA alr;
}
```

My goal is to build a function that gets all the grandchildren of an object of Cluster type.Basically a father can have 0 or more sons which can have at their turn 0 or more sons.

I tried to build a recursive function but all it gives back is only one grandchild using the code down below.
Here is the function I built:

```
public List<classA> getLevel0Clusters(Cluster cluster,List<classA> list)
    {
        if (cluster.LstChildClusters.Count == 0)
        {
            list.Add(cluster.alr);
          return (list);

        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lstChildClusters.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                return (lstChildClusters[i].getLevel0Clusters(lstChildClusters[i], list));
            }
            return (lstChildClusters[0].getLevel0Clusters(lstChildClusters[0], list));
        }

    }
```

I am using those instances for debugging:

```
   Cluster father = new Cluster();
        father.Alr = new Alarm("father");
        Cluster son1 = new Cluster();
        son1.Alr = new Alarm("son1");
        Cluster son2 = new Cluster();
        son2.Alr = new Alarm("son2");
        Cluster grandson1 = new Cluster();
        grandson1.Alr = new Alarm("grandson1");
        Cluster grandson2 = new Cluster();
        grandson2.Alr = new Alarm("grandson2");
        father.LstChildClusters.Add(son1);
        father.LstChildClusters.Add(son2);
        son1.LstChildClusters.Add(grandson1);
        son1.LstChildClusters.Add(grandson2);
List<classA> lst=new lst<ClassA>();
lst=father.getLevel0Clusters(father,  father.LstAlarms);
```

Does anybody has any clue on how to troubleshoot this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I was initially impressed that you provided class defs and sample data, but when I went to test them they don't compile. It would be really helpful if you tested your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your existing code, so I've done a bit of refactoring to make your program simpler.

But first, to answer your direct question, the problem with your existing method is that you're calling `return` before you finish aggregating all of the results. Your code looks at `grandfather` and sees that it has children so it enters the `for` loop and recursively calls itself for `son1`. It sees that `son1` has children so enters the for loop and recursively calls itself for `grandson1` which doesn't have children so it adds `grandson1` to the list and then returns. The outer call returns after finding the first value so the next two levels up just return. Hence the list only has `grandson1`.

So, to refactor your code: The `getLevel0Clusters` method does not need to pass in a `Cluster` (as it is defined in the `Cluster` class it can use `this`) and a `List<classA>` (as it can generate one as needed).

So your `getLevel0Clusters` can become simply this:

```
public List<classA> getLevel0Clusters()
{
    return new[] { this.alr, }
        .Concat(this.LstChildClusters
            .SelectMany(child => child.getLevel0Clusters()))
        .ToList();
}
```

In order to get everything to compile I modified your sample code to be this:

```
Cluster father = new Cluster();
father.alr = new classA("father");
Cluster son1 = new Cluster();
son1.alr = new classA("son1");
Cluster son2 = new Cluster();
son2.alr = new classA("son2");
Cluster grandson1 = new Cluster();
grandson1.alr = new classA("grandson1");
Cluster grandson2 = new Cluster();
grandson2.alr = new classA("grandson2");
father.LstChildClusters.Add(son1);
father.LstChildClusters.Add(son2);
son1.LstChildClusters.Add(grandson1);
son1.LstChildClusters.Add(grandson2);
List<classA> lst = father.getLevel0Clusters();
```

...and your classes as this:

```
public class Cluster
{
    List<Cluster> lstChildClusters = new List<Cluster>();

    public List<Cluster> LstChildClusters
    {
        get { return lstChildClusters; }
        set { lstChildClusters = value; }
    }
    public classA alr;

    public List<classA> getLevel0Clusters()
    {
        return new[] { this.alr, }
            .Concat(this.LstChildClusters
                .SelectMany(child => child.getLevel0Clusters()))
            .ToList();
    }
}

public class classA
{
    public string Name;
    public classA(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

When I ran your sample code I got this result out:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as soon as you find *one* offspring, you return to the calling program.  The value of **Count** has no effect other than **0** versus positive: you enter the loop, call **lstChildClusters[0].getLevel0Clusters(lstChildClusters[0]**, and return that value without bothering to increment **i** and continue the loop.

Instead, your **for** loop has to add each return value to the list.  *After* the loop is done, you can return to the calling program.